# Collapse all the tabs in a Accordion on jquery?

Tags: jquery, accordion

By using the Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC, 
how can I hide all the Accordion Tabs on page loading up ? By default, it will expand the first Accordion tab on page loading up! 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Check this: http://codepen.io/rochapablo/editor/YPXbQM

Answer (score 101):

Try this:

It will disable all the active (open) pane.

```
$('.accordion').accordion({
    active: false,
    collapsible: true            
});
```

Answer (score 5):

View the jQuery, there is most likely an option to specify the tab to show; by default this is probably the first. You can override the behavior by adding additional jQuery.

If the accordion is a nested UL, the jQuery to hide all the nested UL elements would be like this:

`$('ul.accordion ul').hide();`

Be sure to place this after the jQuery that sets up the accordion functionality. Clicking any of the top LI should then show the nested UL.

The markup may be different, but the logic should be very similar.

Comment: thanks for you help, but Telerik Extensions has a little different, show that you can just use the hide function to hide the accordion

Comment: This will hide as you suggested. But active element will be active. So, `active: false`is right thing to do.