# create a single Expand & collapse toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I am a beginner in javascript and want to enablea  toggle function where the Expand All and Collapse all are one button

Please can you help me out with this jsfiddle example?

http://jsfiddle.net/PZHF5/6/

This is one code that i tired to apply that I got from other sources but did not work & Jquery UI conflicts with other scripts...

```
    $("#collapse_toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).data('collapsed') == true){
        $(".topnav").accordion('toggle', true);
        $(this).data('collapsed', false);
        $(this).text("Collapse All");
    }else{
        $(".topnav").accordion('toggle', false);            
        $(this).data('collapsed', true);
        $(this).text("Expand All");
    }

});

<p class="external">
    <a href="#" id="collapse_toggle" data-collapsed="true">Expand All</a>
</p>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You're using an `Accordion` widget. Meaning if you want to "expand all", you're hurting the very first principle of an `accordion`. But you can always workaround this behavior. See this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592494/collapse-all-the-tabs-in-a-accordion-on-jquery)

Comment: Jquery UI conflicts with other scripts...

Comment: You're actually using a different script, not jQuery UI. You might want to link the script, or seek help on the script's github page.