# How to close the first row in accordion function in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to do is close the first row just like the others in the second row and etc. My problem is the first row always open every time users refresh the page or not.

`i want it like this` [image]

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Mp64t/57/

Comment: check it out the accordion properties.

Comment: I find your issue in this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592494/collapse-all-the-tabs-in-a-accordion-on-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mp64t/58/)**

Try [`active`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active) and [`collapsible`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-collapsible) properties,

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({active:false,collapsible:true});
});
```

In the version you are using, just `active:true` won't affect the accordion if you don't set `collapsible` property.

By default, Panels are set to `collapsible:false`

Answer (score 3):

Just add `active` option:

```
$(function() {
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
          active: false
      });
  });
```