# Force accordion to close all tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I tried to search for a solution before asking this question but unfortunately, I can't reach any answer on my code!

I want to force all accordion tabs to close, so the user can open or close as he prefer.

My code is:

```
jQuery(".tap-title").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).click(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).parent().parent().hasClass("toggle-accordion")) {
            jQuery(this).parent().find("li:first .tap-title").addClass("active");
            jQuery(this).parent().find("li:first .tap-title").next(".accordion-inner").addClass("active");
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
            jQuery(this).next(".accordion-inner").slideToggle().toggleClass("active");
            jQuery(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus").toggleClass("fa-minus");
        }else {
            if (jQuery(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
                jQuery(this).parent().parent().find(".tap-title").removeClass("active").next().slideUp(200);
                jQuery(this).parent().parent().find(".tap-title").next().removeClass("active").slideUp(200);
                jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideDown(200);
                jQuery(this).next(".accordion-inner").toggleClass("active");
                jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("i").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
                jQuery(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
            }
        }
        return false;

    });
});
```

My HTML code is:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="title-section text-left">
            <h4 class="bold">Normal Horizontal Tabs</h4>
        </div>      
        <scrip> 
        <div class="accordions-style1">
            <div class="section-content">
                <h4 class="tap-title active"><a href="#">What Is Yamen?<i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a></h4>
                <div class="tap-inner" style="display: block;">
                    <p>Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque ut. Vivamus at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-content">
                <h4 class="tap-title"><a href="#">Why Should I purchase this template?<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></h4>
                <div class="tap-inner" style="display: none;">
                    <p>Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque ut. Vivamus at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-content">
                <h4 class="tap-title"><a href="#">What about features?<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></h4>
                <div class="tap-inner" style="display: none;">
                    <p>Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque ut. Vivamus at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: which accordion?? accordion jquery-ui?? or your custom accordion?? .. in all cases provide your html to let us know whats parent of and next with ... etc .. and its much better to make a [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code

Comment: I just updated the question with my HTML code. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: you still haven't answered @Mohamed-Yousef question about what type of accordion you're using. Or included the javascript code where you make the html into an accordion.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just bought a template and trying to customize it with 0 Javascript experience :) So unfortunately, I don't know the type of accordion

Comment: Wallahy ya handasa ma 3aref a2ol eh :( .. tab asa3dak ezay delwa2ty?

Comment: hahaha, gazak Allah kol 5er anyway :) I've a template with this code structure, and really I don't know what is the type of this accordion. If it matters, the templates built based on Twitter Bootstrap V3

Comment: @mohamed-yousef When i remove the active class, it just removing the color in css, but the color appear again when open/close tabs

Comment: remove active class from class="tap-title active" << remove active from here ..and change <div class="tap-inner" style="display: block;">  to <div class="tap-inner" style="display: none;">

Comment: I know it will work now .. but we should check that everything works well after made this changes

Comment: I tried this also with no chance. There should be a jQuery code to add, but I didn't know what is the proper one. i tried several times before asking the question here

Comment: you copied that code from console? or from your template code??

Comment: Of course from the template :) ya handasa ana 3ndy 5alfeya msh ledaragdy :D hwa el jquery bs elly malesh feh experience 5ales 3'er 3la 5afef

Comment: Ya 5ofy mn el 5alfyat de :) .. tab ta3ala face w ha7elehalak ISA .. kolo 3shan 5ater masr :) .. hat el face law yenfa3

Comment: Hahaha, thank you. This is my account http://fb.com/habaza

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer on my question with @mohamed-yousef help, thank you very much mate.

I replaced my jQuery code with this one:

```
jQuery(".tap-title").each(function(){
    jQuery(this).click(function() {
        if (jQuery(this).parent().parent().hasClass("toggle-accordion")) {
            jQuery(this).parent().find("li:first .tap-title").addClass("active");
            jQuery(this).parent().find("li:first .tap-title").next(".accordion-inner").addClass("active");
            jQuery(this).toggleClass("active");
            jQuery(this).next(".accordion-inner").slideToggle().toggleClass("active");
            jQuery(this).find("i").toggleClass("fa-plus").toggleClass("fa-minus");
        }else {
            if (jQuery(this).next().is(":hidden")) {
                jQuery(this).parent().parent().find(".tap-title").removeClass("active").next().slideUp(200);
                jQuery(this).parent().parent().find(".tap-title").next().removeClass("active").slideUp(200);
                jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideDown(200);
                jQuery(this).next(".accordion-inner").toggleClass("active");
                jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("i").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
                jQuery(this).find("i").removeClass("fa-plus").addClass("fa-minus");
        }else{
                jQuery(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle(200);
                jQuery(this).next(".accordion-inner").toggleClass("active");
                jQuery(this).parent().parent().find("i").removeClass("fa-minus").addClass("fa-plus");
        }
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

And replaced my HTML code with this one:

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="title-section text-left">
            <h4 class="bold">Normal Horizontal Tabs</h4>
        </div>      
        <scrip> 
        <div class="accordions-style1">
            <div class="section-content">
                <h4 class="tap-title"><a href="#">What Is Yamen?<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></h4>
                <div class="tap-inner" style="display: none;">
                    <p>Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque ut. Vivamus at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-content">
                <h4 class="tap-title"><a href="#">Why Should I purchase this template?<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></h4>
                <div class="tap-inner" style="display: none;">
                    <p>Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque ut. Vivamus at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section-content">
                <h4 class="tap-title"><a href="#">What about features?<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a></h4>
                <div class="tap-inner" style="display: none;">
                    <p>Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque ut. Vivamus at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod scelerisque at elit quis urna adipiscing , Curabitur vitae velit in neque dictum blandit. Duis dapibus aliquam mi, eget euismod sceler ut.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, just as a friendly piece of advice, you can replace `jquery()` functions with `$()`, (eg. `$('.tap-title').each(function(){...});)`

Second of all, although I don't quite understand your structure of your HTML as you didn't supply that with your question, but by the looks of it, it looks as if you are toggling the accordion with classes?

So I would do something along the lines of targeting the .active class and then removing the .active class on itself and sliding it up? Supplying the HTML code would have helped me a lot, but hope this helps.

Comment: I just updated the question with my HTML code. I appreciate your help :)

Comment: Try this: inside of the jquery(this).click(function(){...}); at the top: $(this).parent().slideUp(200); and $(this).removeClass('active');

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't understand you well :)

Actually I just bought a template and trying with 0 Javascript background to customize it

Comment: No Problem, check the finished JavaScript code in the pastebin and let me know how it works :) http://pastebin.com/7K2LDRHq

Comment: I tried to replace my code with the one you provided but unfortunately, it didn't work. Actually. now I can't open nor close tabs.

Comment: Try it now, if it doesn't work give me the error in the console, because I've only added two lines.... http://pastebin.com/3xJLnney

Comment: I tried again, now when I click on a tab, it disappear! And there's no log in the console which is weird! NOTE: I'm working in a localhost

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jquery-ui accordion I believe this will work:

```
$('.ui-accordion-header').removeClass('ui-accordion-header-active ui-state-active ui-corner-top').addClass('ui-corner-all').attr({
    'aria-selected': 'false',
    'tabindex': '-1'
});
$('.ui-accordion-header-icon').removeClass(icons.headerSelected).addClass(icons.header);
$('.ui-accordion-content').removeClass('ui-accordion-content-active').attr({
    'aria-expanded': 'false',
    'aria-hidden': 'true'
 }).hide();
```

Comment: and what about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592494/collapse-all-the-tabs-in-a-accordion-on-jquery ??

Comment: I just updated the question with my HTML code. I appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Basic Accordion:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="accordion">
  <div class="accordion-head">
    title here
  </div>
  <div class="accordion-body">
    content here
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.accordion-body{
   display:none;
}
```

**jQuery** (or $() instead of jQuery())

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  var items = jQuery('.accordion');
  var heads = items.find('.accordion-head);


  heads.click(function(){

     var i = jQuery(this);

     items.find('.accordion-body').slideUp(); // close all accordions
     i.next('.accordion-body').slideDown();


  });

});
```

Comment: I just updated the question with my HTML code. I appreciate your help :)